# Why is present perfect not possible in this case

Tags: present-perfect

Two days ago I tried to order a book but could not pay because your system  **has not accepted** Paypal payments **yet**.

I don't understand why present perfect with yet can not be used

yet means that one day the system will accept this payment but not now, so I really don't understand why it is not possible.

Comment: (You already asked essentially the same question.)

Comment: Yes but I have not understood the answer!!!

Comment: I understand your problem, but asking the same Q twice is frowned on here. But I see that all you got in response to the earlier Q was a few comments from myself & Kate, not a proper "Answer" (if you don't understand something posted as a genuine Answer, obviously you would just post a comment asking for clarification). Anyway, I couldn't do this 18 hours ago, because a Q has to have been up for 2 days before it's possible to place a "bounty" on it. But 2 days *have* passed now, so I've put a bounty on the earlier Q. That should get you a better response.